# How to wait for persisted user from firebase auth in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I use firebase auth in my React Native App (via expo), authentication works fine via an observer, including persistent user:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        this.props.setUser(user);
    }
}).bind(this);
```

I show a landing screen with login/sign-up and if the user is signed in with an account I forward to the main app. After the app start, it takes a moment for the *onAuthStateChanged* method to fire when loading a persistent user, which leads my app to show this landing screen for a short time and then to navigate away. **I would prefer to have a loading screen until the auth state is determined properly.**

But if there is no persistent user the onAuthStateChanged never triggers, so I do not have a specific event to wait for. I could use a timeout timer, but this seems to be a bad solution because of the necessary waiting time may vary greatly depending on hardware and connection speed.

**How to solve this properly, i.e. how do I know there is no persistent user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase error block when user does not persist](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth.html#optionalerror:function)

```
var isLoading = true;

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            isLoading = false;
            this.props.setUser(user);
        }
    }, error => {
       isLoading = false;
   }
}).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The onAuthStateChanged will only trigger it's function when it has completed loading. So when triggered you can assume the authentication has completed loading regardless of the value of user. I ended up using the expo-splash-screen to display a loading screen while the auth was loading.

Example:

```
export default () => {
    const [isAuthenticationLoaded, setIsAuthenticationLoaded] = React.useState(false);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) setUser(user);
        setIsAuthenticationLoaded(true);
    });

   React.useEffect(() => {
        SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticationLoaded) {
            SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [isAuthenticationLoaded]);
    ...
}
```